# [model-theory] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

It seems odd there's a [proof-theory] tag but no [model-theory] tag. What's the one without the other?

Comment: Such a tag could be useful. If we collect a list of questions it could apply to here, any high-rep users can help tag them properly.

Comment: Some recent examples follow, having trouble with this editor: Example of non-isomorphic structures which are elementarily equivalent (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1563) Is there a natural model of Peano Arithmetic where Goodstein's theorem fails? (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3609) Does this proposition hold if Mod(Γ)=∅ ? (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4135)

Comment: I've added a model-theory tag to these 3 questions.

Comment: @muad - Thanks. That should start to give it some legitimacy. (It is of course already a tag at MO.)